How do I rename my token from showing unknown token on solscan
I'm using the spl-token 2022 program and after adding the metadata details via cli, i still get the unknown token when i lookup my token on solscan, here an example looking at it on dev net.

Do you getting any kind of error like: #[error("Account does not support specified authority type")]

Support for token-2022 metadata hasn't been added to the Solana explorer yet, so this is unfortunately expected behavior

so, who can genuinely guide me on how to create a token and deploy its metadata to display name and logo.
perhaps a link or page, something that really works.
